# How access values from different classes without using parameters in java?

Tags: java, oop

For example, my program is like that,
one java file,this is my fixed class.

```
class Dynamic{
 String s;
  public void program(){
   System.out.println(s);
   }
}
```

here another java file,this is class dynamic,

```
class Source{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
 String s = "Hello world";
 Dynamic d=new Dynamic();
 d.program();
 }}
```

I want to print s in dynamic class. And I don't want to use s as a parameter and also If I changes my sources class, it will works. Is any other method is there?

Comment: Yeah you can declare s as public and static

Comment: In java it's a convention to start the class name with capital letter like - Dynamic, Source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may make `String s` of `dynamic` class public static -

```
public static String s;
```

Then you can get it from any where like this -

```
dynamic.s
```

But in OOP worlds making variable public is not recommended.

You can also make a public `getter` method like this (the best way) in your `dynamic` class-

```
public String getS(){
 return this.s;
}
```

Comment: Still I am getting null on s..

Comment: Because you didn't set the value for `s`. In you declaration you may set the value for `s` like this - `String s = "someSampleString";`

Comment: public class Source {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  Dynamic d=new Dynamic();
   d.program();
   Dynamic.s = "sahtish"; String s="sathish";
 }
}                  public class Dynamic {
 public static String s;
 public String getS(){
  return this.s;
 }
 public void program(){
  System.out.println(s);
 }
} . this is my new code..but it prints null..

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using "global variables". But i don't know if is this what you are looking for.

```
class Source{
  public static String s = "Hello world";
  public static void Main(String args[]) {
    dynamic d=new dynamic;
    d.program();
  }
}

class Dynamic{
  public void program(){
    System.out.println(Source.s);
  }
}
```

Anyway, as a style rule, classes's names should be in CamelCase.

Comment: But Source calss is dynamically changing. IF use another class means. I want to create a jar file using Dynamic class and source file is client side how would i get that one..

Comment: For this reason you say you don't want to pass s as parameter?
For this problem i think you can use Interfaces, do you think it it can be good for you?

Comment: K thankz. I will try it on.